# SqlDeveloper installation on Mac OS El Capitan

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to install sqldeveloper on mac os but it fails to start. I cross verified to make sure the JAVA_HOME is set but still getting the following exception. Anyone faced this issue? I am using Java 1.8 and SQL developer version 4.1.3.

```
sqldeveloper.sh: line 4: cd: sqldeveloper.sh: Not a directory
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initializeProperties(Framework.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalInit(EquinoxLauncher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.init(EquinoxLauncher.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.Netbinox.init(Netbinox.java:84)
    at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.prepare(Netigso.java:167)
    at org.netbeans.NetigsoHandle.turnOn(NetigsoHandle.java:138)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1339)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1156)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:340)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:181)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:150)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:307)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: setSeed() failed
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implSetSeed(NativePRNG.java:458)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$300(NativePRNG.java:329)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineSetSeed(NativePRNG.java:212)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:209)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.UniversalUniqueIdentifier.computeNodeAddress(UniversalUniqueIdentifier.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.UniversalUniqueIdentifier.<clinit>(UniversalUniqueIdentifier.java:35)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:313)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implSetSeed(NativePRNG.java:456)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Are you trying to install the application by calling **sqldeveloper.sh** manually from some shell prompt?

Comment: Please provide more detail on the exact procedure, you are following. Are you in line with http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-install-mac-1969675.html?

Comment: Yes I did as described in the oracle. I have JDK running successfully for my IDE and everything so seems to have no issues there. If I open the Sql Developer through Applications it opens and gets killed immediately. So I ran it manually from shell prompt and was able to find this error.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but for anyone coming here with the same problem: The Java 7 default entropy gathering device is `/dev/urandom` which might not be writable on Mac OS X systems (not sure about the exact conditions).
To work around this either use Java 8 (where the default is `/dev/random` anyway) or declare `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/random` in the java call (or via the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable, if you can't change the calling script)